# Estimotes Indoor how to fetch location

Tags: ios, location, swift2, ibeacon, estimote

I use this method just can cell one location. I want to ask this method can cell my all location?

```
manager.fetchUserLocationsWithSuccess({ (response) in 
    let locations = response as! [ESTLocation]
    if let kitchen = locations.filter({ $0.identifier == locationname }).first {
        self.location = kitchen
        self.indoorLocationView.positionView = self.positionView
        self.indoorLocationView.drawLocation(self.location)
        self.manager.startIndoorLocation(self.location)
        self.title = self.location?.name
    } else { 
        print("location not found")
    }
}, failure: { (error: NSError!) in 
    print("error when fetching locations: \(error)")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This method already returns a list of all your locations:

```
let locations = response as! [ESTLocation]
```

And then, in the subsequent line, this array of all your locations is being filtered to find the location with `identifier` equal to whatever `locationname` is set to:

```
let kitchen = locations.filter({ $0.identifier == locationname }).first
```

So if you want to operate on all of your locations, just get rid of the filter and use the `locations` variable instead.

Comment: sorry i can't understand about location variable,can you explain more? thanks!